# multiple users sending request to backend at the same time

Tags: javascript, mongodb, firebase, async-await

I am currently learning about Mern stack  (sending request from frontend to backend) and a thought occur to me: what would happen if multiple users is sending request at the exact same time to backend to fetch data?  Is there any industry standard to deal with this problem?

The code is normally how i typically get request just for context, or is there any resources about this issue i can do more research on?

*Frontend*

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    // Define the API endpoint URL
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/data';

    // Make a GET request using the native fetch API
    const response = await fetch(apiUrl);

    // Check if the response status is OK (200)
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    // Parse the response as JSON
    const responseData = await response.json();

    // Access the data from the response
    console.log('Data from API:', responseData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
  }
};

// Call the fetchData function
fetchData();
```

*backend*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

// Sample data
const responseData = { message: 'Hello from the backend!' };

// API endpoint for fetching data
app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  res.json(responseData);
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Everything will work the way you expect, multiple users sending at the same time is not something you need to worry about.

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase or MongoDB?

Comment: @GregFenton I added the tag because I'm planning to use MongoDB/Firebase as my backend. just in case  anyone who has experience with these databases might to chip in their knowledge of any features or design principles of such database that help prevent/ mitigate issues caused by multiple simultaneous requests , because i might not be aware of such aspects

Comment: @Habby thank you for your clarification and detailed explanation , learned something new today!

Comment: @trox the main thing about Firebase is that it is a "serverless" backend and that, for the most part, you do not need to write "middleware" or a "backend". Your UI can directly interact with the database, and concurrency constructs are fundamental to the architecture.  You *can* use a backend server if you require one, but many (most?) apps built on Firebase do not use additional backend "server-based" technologies.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple users send requests to the backend at the same time, the backend needs to handle these requests concurrently. In a normal scenario, a BE server can handle multiple request simultaneously by creating separate threads or processes for each incoming request.
Specifically Node.js is designed to be **non-blocking** and asynchronous allowing it to handle many concurrent connections efficiently.

Some considerations and potential issues can be:

1. **Concurrency and Thread Safety**: make sure your be code is designed to be thread-safe if you're using threads or process. (in node the event-driven and non blocking nature eliminates some common concurrency issues)
2. **DB Operations**: if you use a DB, be mindful of how the db handles concurrent requests. DB usually have ways to manage concurrent access. check for handling transactions and locking appropriately.
3. **Rate limiting**: To prevent abuse or unintended traffic, consider implementing rate limiting on your API
4. **Scalability**: As your application grows, keep in mind horizontal scaling by deploying your BE on multiple servers or using technologies like load balancing
5. **Asynchronous Operations**: if your code involves async operations, make sure to correctly implement Promises and async awaits

Comment: This looks like a LLM generated answer which is [banned on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: I wrote it, the only thing is that i used deepL to translate part of the explanation, English is not my native language :(
maybe that's why some sentences seem generated and some verbs out of place